# C++ - Most efficient way to return largest element in vector less than given input

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Given an unsorted vector and an input element of the same type, what is the most efficient way to find the largest element in the vector that is less than the given element? This is what I have so far:

```
std::vector<double> vec{1,2.2,3.5,4};
double elem = 3;

double lessThan(double elem, std::vector<double> vec) 
{
    std::vector<double> tmp = vec;
    tmp.push_back(elem);
    sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    return *(find(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), elem) - 1);
}

lessThan(elem, vec); //returns 2.2
```

Thanks

Comment: It is funny. I am the only one who showed the correct and the best approach instead of bla..bla.bla. And you entirely igonre the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, don't pass the vector by value as copying the vector causes a pass of the values and writes into memory which is just expensive and unnecessary.

Next, don't `sort()` the elements: that's just expensive and unnecessary. Just do a linear search memorizing the largest suitable value found so far. You can probably use `max_element()` and consider elements which are bigger than the cut-off value to be an equality class.

I could write the code but I don't want to spoil your entertainment solving the homework assignment.

Comment: Thanks. I've modified the code to use max_element and remove_if as follows:
`return *max_element(vec.begin(), remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&] (double& d) {return d > elem;} ) );`

Would this be more efficient?

Comment: @user3294195: it is certainly more efficient than the original but it still traverses the range twice and modifies the range. You are much better off only using `max_element()` with a suitable predicted, e.g., something like `[=](double d0, double d1){ return d0 < d1? d1 < elem: d0 < elem? false: d1 < elem; }` (I think this is the correct expression but I'm not entirely sure).

Comment: @user3294195 You may not use std::max_element in your case. Why do you ignore the only correct approach I showed?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to write your own function.:) For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double>::const_iterator lessThan( const std::vector<double> &v, 
                                              double value ) 
{
    auto first = v.begin();

    while ( first != v.end() && !( *first < value ) ) ++first;

    auto max = first;

    for ( ; first != v.end(); ++first )
    {
        if ( *first < value && *max < *first ) max = first;
    }

    return max;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 1, 2.2, 3.5, 4 };
    double value = 3.0;

    auto max = lessThan( v, value );

    if ( max != v.cend() )
    {
        std::cout << "The maximum value less than " << value
                  << " is " << *max << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The maximum value less than 3 is 2.2
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad from Moscow. I ended up going with this solution as it traverses the range only once. As you mentioned, I don't think max_element can be used unless combined with another function (such as remove_if), and that requires multiple traversals.

Comment: BTW, it aborts if `value` is less than all elements in `v`.

Comment: @user3294195 See my code. There is a check whether the returned iterator is equal to cend(). In this case it means that the element is not found.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate a predicate in the function that returns `min_element` if `value` is less than all elements in `v`? I can add `if (value < *min_element(v.begin(), v.end()) ) return min_element(v.begin(), v.end() )` before the `while` loop, but this will lead to 2 traversals whenever value is within bounds.

Comment: @user3294195  I have not understood the question, What do you mean saying about predicate?

Comment: Sorry, so if `value` is less than all elements in `v`, is there a way to add a functionality within the function itself so that it returns `min_element`? The `cend()` code is in `main()` and not within the function.

Comment: @user3294195  Again I have understood nothing. What is the problem with cend()? It is used to check wjether the target element is found. What are you going to do with cend()?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dietmar Kühl for the advice.
I made this version for homework:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm> 

int main ()
{
   std::vector<double> vec{2.7,1,2.2,3.5,4,2.8,3.0};
   double elem = 3;
   auto it = std::max_element(vec.begin(),vec.end(),
   [elem](const double &x,const double &y)
   {
    if(y<elem & x<y) return true;
    else return false;
   });
   std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to replace `y<elem & x<y` by `y<elem && x<y`. Although the bitwise and operator probably works OK in this situation, you really want to use the logic an operator.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm It is simply a wrong approach. std::max_element may not be used in this case.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow , why you so think?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm Function std::max_element  unconditionally returns a valid iterator even in case when the array doe not contain an element that satisfies the requirement. For example try to find element that is less than 1 in your array..

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, thanks for clarification. But add one   
validation and implementation will be correct.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm You are wrong. If the first element in the sequence has is maximum then it always wilol be returned. You showed simply a wrong solution.